# Комментарий вместо ответа

Tags: обсуждение, faq

По [правилам](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) сайта комментарии не предназначены для дачи ответов:

> ### Когда не следует оставлять комментарий?
>
> **ответ на вопрос** или альтернатива уже существующим ответам; вместо этого лучше отправьте полноценный ответ (или внесите правки и дополнения в уже существующий).

Пожалуйста, не забывайте об этом: все нарушения **будут удаляться**, так как преобразовать комментарий в ответ технически невозможно.

### Для чего нужны комментарии?

- чтобы попросить автора уточнить вопрос;
- чтобы представить конструктивную критику, которая поможет автору улучшить сообщение;
- чтобы сделать уместное дополнение, содержащее не самую распространенную информацию, или, возможно, описание временного явления (например, ссылку на соответствующий вопрос или предупреждение автору о том, что вопрос был обновлен).

Answer (score 2):

Что касается комментариев к вопросам, мне нечего добавить.

Но я нередко комментирую другие ответы, если, на мой взгляд, они содержат слабые места (неправильно понят вопрос, не рассмотрены критично важные случаи и т.п.). Или если что-то в ответе выглядит совсем уж сомнительным (на моём уровне понимания). Даже в тех случаях, когда вина ошибки/непонимания лежит на мне, я считаю, что будущим пользователям будет полезно увидеть, какие возникали сомнения у других участников, и как они были разрешены.

Если бы я вносил "идейные" правки в ответы даже в случае полной уверенности в ошибке, вряд ли это сказалось бы положительно на внутреннем климате, поэтому я предпочитаю пользоваться комментариями. Но есть одно исключение, когда я хотел бы править ответы, даже рискуя испортить отношения — пропаганда любительской этимологии. Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы запрет на этимологические "версии", подпадающие под формальные критерии "любительской этимологии" А.Зализняка, был узаконен в правилах форума.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ! Будьте добры, создайте отдельное обсуждение для вашего предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Понимаю этот пост как приглашение к дискуссии. Я думаю, следует не только следовать правилам, но и корректировать правила, приводя их в соответствие с жизненными реалиями. Давайте рассмотрим различные ситуации.

1. Вместо ответа — совет автору вопроса, как решить задачу самостоятельно. Мое мнение: легитимно.
2. Автор комментария поясняет, расширяет, дополняет вопрос. Мое мнение: допустимо в разумных пределах.
3. Неполный ответ на вопрос. Автор комментария не может дать полный ответ, но не хочет получать минусы и замечания. Однако полных ответов нет, а неполный ответ лучше, чем ничего. Мое мнение: спорно, лучше дать неполный ответ и пояснить, что он неполный.
4. Автор комментария дает ответ, но не совсем уверен в своей правоте, тем не менее считает полезным поделиться. При этом не хочет получать минусы и замечания. Мое мнение: стоит оформить как ответ и пояснить, что ответ этот — спорный.

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ! Несколько замечаний: 1) поскольку для нас важно, чтобы решение могли увидеть и понять все пользователи, необходимо публиковать его в ответе; 2) радикально изменять (дополнять) вопрос почти никогда не стоит, ведь есть другое правило: разные вопросы должны задаваться по отдельности. В остальном согласен!